# Help needed to convert a javascript object to corresponding C# dictionary

Tags: c#, javascript, dictionary

Hi I'm kind of newbie in C#, I have this javascript code that I need to convert into corresponding c# dictionary

given below is the javascript code

```
 EXCHANGES = {
        "ICE": {
            source: "SPC",
            name: "ICE Futures Europe",
            assetTypes: {
                CER: {
                    spot: "ECX CER DAILY FUTURE",
                    fut: "ECX CER FUTURE"
                },
                EUA: {
                    spot: "ECX EUA DAILY FUTURE",
                    fut: "ECX EUA FUTURE"
                }
            }
        },
        "CLIMEX": {
            source: "CLX",
            name: "Climex Spot Market",
            symbols: {
                CER: {
                    spot: ["CER"]
                },
                EUA: {
                    spot: ["EUA 08-12"]
                }
            }
        },
        "BLUENEXT": {
            source: "BLNXT",
            name: "Bluenext",
            symbols: {
                CER: {
                    spot: ["1000019-82-1"]
                },
                EUA: {
                    spot: ["1000019-81-1"]
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

So far what I have manage is this

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Exchanges = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> {
            {"ICE ECX", new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {"source", "SPC"},
                {"name", "ICE Futures Europe"},
                {"exchange", "ICE" }
            }},
            {"Climex", new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {"source", "CLX"},
                {"name", "Climex Spot Market"},
                {"exchange", "Climex" }
            }},
            {"BlueNext", new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {"source", "BLNXT"},
                {"name", "Bluenext"},
                {"exchange", "BlueNext" }
            }},
            {"Green Exchange", new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {"source", "SPC"},
                {"name", "NYMEX: Futures"},
                {"exchange", "NYMEX" }
            }},
            {"NYMEX_FA", new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {"source", "SPC"},
                {"name", "NYMEX: Futures Acess"},
                {"exchange", "NYMEX_FA" }
            }}
        };
```

Can anyone of you can guide me to the correct way to do this any help will be appreciated.
thanks 
Pranay

Comment: Do you have .NET 4.0? This can make your conversion a bit easier because of the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a JSON Parser. Like [this](http://json.codeplex.com/).
In that way you can retrieve the properties and values after parsing from the `JObject`.

```
string jsonText = @"{
  prop1: 1, 
  prop2: 'Some String',
  'prop3': {
    iProp1: 1,
    iProp2: 2
}";
JObject parsedJson = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
```

Comment: This is indeed the easiest way. Also, be sure to reference the deserialized obect as an Expandoobject as ChaosPandion correctly observed. This will save you from having to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give a try to **ExpandoObject**, which is dynamic and implements *IDictionary<string,object>.* For instance, you can write the following code:

```
dynamic x = new ElasticObject();
x.Ice = new ExpandoObject();
x.Ice.Source = "SPC";
x.Ice.Name = "Ice Futures Europe";
x.AssetTypes = new ExpandoObject();
x.AssetTypes.CER = new ExpandoObject();
x.AssetTypes.CER.Spot = "EXC CER DAILY FUTURE";
x.AssetTypes.CER.Fut = "EXC CER FUTURE";
x.EUA = new ExpandoObject();
x.EUA.Spot = "ECX EUA DAILY FUTURE";
x.EUA.Fut = "ECX EUA FUTURE";
```

On MSDN you can read more about ExpandoObject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

If you need a yet smarter object, there is the **ElasticObject** (described [here](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/02/introducing-elasticobject-for-net-40.html)). Using it you can skip the declaration of the nested Expandos, like this:

```
dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
x.Ice.Source = "SPC";
x.Ice.Name = "Ice Futures Europe";
x.AssetTypes.CER.Spot = "EXC CER DAILY FUTURE";
x.AssetTypes.CER.Fut = "EXC CER FUTURE";
x.EUA.Spot = "ECX EUA DAILY FUTURE";
x.EUA.Fut = "ECX EUA FUTURE";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx Hemme for your solution but unfortunately ExpandoObject works only in C# 4.0 and I'm still stuck in C#2.0

Answer (score 0):

This what I did basically I created classes since maintaining this level of dictionary would have been cumbersome

```
public class Exchange
        {
            public string Source {get; set;}
            public string Name {get; set;}
            public Dictionary<string, AssetTypeSymbol> AssetTypes {get; set;}
            public Dictionary <string,AssetTypeSymbol>Symbols {get; set;}
        }
        public class AssetTypeSymbol
        {
            public IList<string> Spot {get; set;}
            public IList<string> Fut {get; set;}
        }

    public Dictionary<string,Exchange> Exchanges = new Dictionary<string,Exchange>
    {
            {"ICE ECX", new Exchange() {
                Source = "SPC",
                Name = "ICE Futures Europe",
                AssetTypes = new Dictionary<string, AssetTypeSymbol>() {
                    {"CER", new AssetTypeSymbol() {
                        Spot = new string[] { "ECX CER DAILY FUTURE" },
                        Fut = new string[] { "ECX CER FUTURE" }
                    }},
                    .......... and so on
```